# Given a matrix, how to find the best cell for each row, without repetition

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, algebra

I have a matrix, the rows are objects, and the columns are objectives, each row represents the distance from an object to an objective.

For example, lets consider I have 3 objects O1 O2 O3, and 3 objectives, OA OB OC, the matrix will be something like

```
   | OA OB OC
-------------
O1 | 2  4  6
O2 | 1  2  8
O3 | 3  5  3
```

I just filled it with random data, probably it doesn't make sense, but it may be useful for the problem.

The output I expect is: O2-OA, O1-OB and O3-OC

So although OA is the bearer objective to O1, since OA is already used by OA, it goes to the next one.

Comment: This is the Traveling Salesman problem

Comment: It's not clear at all what is your optimisation criterion.

Comment: For example, if O2 chooses OB and O1 chooses OA, total sum will be smaller.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if O1 chooses OA and O2 chooses OB? That would sum to 7 instead of 8 as it stands with your expectation.

Comment: no, because it is a tracking problem, and I dont want tags to change, so it is more likely than O2 is OA

Comment: _"since OA is already used by OA"_ Huh?

Comment: By "tracking problem," do you mean that you don't know OB and OC until you have chosen OA? I don't understand your optimization criterion either. If you just want to find the minimal element in the column whose index has not yet been used, this is not a difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the [*Linear Assignment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_assignment_problem) problem.

An optimal solution can be found in O(N^3) time using the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), for which there is a decent Python implementation with further information [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres/).

If you want to get a feel for how the Hungarian Algorithm works - [this lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUGIhEecipE) is definitely worth watching.

If speed is important, a method which *can* return optimal solutions quickly (although - as far as I can tell - is not guaranteed to do so) is the so-called [Softassign algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.33.3701&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which related to [Simulated Annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing), and involves iterative row and column normalisation of the cost matrix.

Finally, it is of course possible to solve this quickly in a sub-optimal fashion using a greedy method where the best match is chosen sequentially until all assignments are made.